# Equivalent of Matlab "whos" command for Lua interpreter?

Tags: matlab, lua, octave, ipython

What is the Lua equivalent of the Octave/Matlab/IPython "whos" command?  I'm trying to learn Lua interactively and would like to see what variables are currently defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All global variables in Lua reside in a table available as global variable [`_G`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-_G) (yes, _G._G == _G). Therefore if you want to list all global variable, you can iterate over the table using `pairs()`:

```
function whos()
    for k,v in pairs(_G) do
        print(k, type(v), v) -- you can also do more sophisticated output here
    end
end
```

Note that this will also give you all the Lua base functions and modules. You can filter them out by checking for a value in a table which you can create on startup when no global variables other than Lua-provided are defined:

```
-- whos.lua
local base = {}
for k,v in pairs(_G) do
    base[k] = true
end
return function()
    for k,v in pairs(_G) do
        if not base[k] then print(k, type(v), v) end
    end
end
```

Then, you can use this module as follows:

```
$ lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> whos = require 'whos'
> a = 1
> b = 'hello world!'
> whos()
a   number  1
b   string  hello world!
whos    function    function: 0x7f986ac11490
```

Local variables are a bit tougher - you have to use [Lua's debug facilities](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.getlocal) - but given that you want to use it interactively, you should only need globals.