# Get all Lua libraries and keywords from the Lua engine

Tags: c#, lua

I'm working on a Code completion control for my Lua IDE

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE

I'm using reflection to get the C# objects info accesable from scripts, but I also want to have Lua specific stuff in the list, like the math lib etc.

Are there any way of getting these? Would also like to get all keywords like if, then, end etc

Comment: Visual Studio has LUA support.  Why do we need another IDE?

Comment: Its a custom software, check the url before posting please

Comment: Slightly related - [Lua equivalent of Matlab "whos" command"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892696/equivalent-of-matlab-whos-command-for-lua-interpreter/9893157#9893157) - you will just need to "go deeper" for modules.

Answer (score 6):

> Are there any way of getting these?

The manual contains everything, but you could also iterate through the global namespace on startup to get everything (you'll have to do this early, before you add anything to the namespace!). If something is a table, then it's also a namespace like `string` or `table` and you can iterate through that to get the methods.

```
local exclude = { _G = true, _VERSION = true, arg = true }
for name, value in pairs(_G) do
    if not exclude[name] then
        print(name)
        if type(value) == 'table' then
            for name, value in pairs(value) do
                print('\t', name)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Produces the following:

```
string
                sub
                upper
                len
                gfind
                rep
                find
                match
                char
                dump
                gmatch
                reverse
                byte
                format
                gsub
                lower
xpcall
package
                preload
                loadlib
                loaded
                loaders
                cpath
                config
                path
                seeall
tostring
print
os
                exit
                setlocale
                date
                getenv
                difftime
                remove
                time
                clock
                tmpname
                rename
                execute
unpack
require
getfenv
setmetatable
next
assert
tonumber
io
                lines
                write
                close
                flush
                open
                output
                type
                read
                stderr
                stdin
                input
                stdout
                popen
                tmpfile
rawequal
collectgarbage
getmetatable
module
rawset
math
                log
                max
                acos
                huge
                ldexp
                pi
                cos
                tanh
                pow
                deg
                tan
                cosh
                sinh
                random
                randomseed
                frexp
                ceil
                floor
                rad
                abs
                sqrt
                modf
                asin
                min
                mod
                fmod
                log10
                atan2
                exp
                sin
                atan
debug
                getupvalue
                debug
                sethook
                getmetatable
                gethook
                setmetatable
                setlocal
                traceback
                setfenv
                getinfo
                setupvalue
                getlocal
                getregistry
                getfenv
pcall
table
                setn
                insert
                getn
                foreachi
                maxn
                foreach
                concat
                sort
                remove
newproxy
type
coroutine
                resume
                yield
                status
                wrap
                create
                running
select
gcinfo
pairs
rawget
loadstring
ipairs
dofile
setfenv
load
error
loadfile
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the next level, the arguments?  The inner value is not a table, without that info the above tree is pretty useless, thanks